# How to use ILogger from outside of the dotnet core web API folder structure?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a dotnet core web api application and I am creating a custom class outside of the standard folders.

```
/Controllers/
/Components/CustomClass.cs
Startup.cs
```

So my CustomClass looks like:

```
public class CustomClass
{
      private readonly ILogger<CustomClass> _logger;

      public CustomClass()
      {          
      }
}
```

I see that there is a ILogger interface here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0

In my dotnet core Web API, do I have to use dependancy injection somehow to get the logger that my web API is using?

I want to use my CustomClass inside of a controller, how do I use that Logger in this scenerio?

Comment: You can resolve the logger from anywhere and then manually pass it to the constructor of your class. The `ILogger<T>` is a convenient way to assign a category to a logger. It's the way to directly get it from DI. You can create a `ILogger` manual by resolving first a `ILoggerFactory` and then call `.CreateLogger("mycategory")`. When you have the logger you can wherever you want in the same class or any other, by constructor or method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomClass
{
      private readonly ILogger<CustomClass> _logger;

      public CustomClass(ILogger logger)
      {
         _logger = logger;          
      }
}
```

Register everything in Startup.

Comment: But I create a new instance on every request, and my constructor has other arguments that I need to pass in that vary on a per request basis.

Comment: You can't assign `ILogger` in `ILogger<CustomClass>`. But you can assign `ILogger<CustomClass>` in `ILogger`.